# Adsense Ads not working in Google AMP cache

Tags: wordpress, caching, amp-html

**CMS:** WordPress

**Theme:** Genesis

**Plugins:** AMP, AMP for WP, W3 Total Cache

Adsense ads are working properly when viewed from my domain: https://www.gokuldeepak.com/become-sub-inspector-police-tamilnadu/amp/

But when I'm viewing it from google AMP cache domain then the ads are not displaying. Only empty space is shown. https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.gokuldeepak.com/become-sub-inspector-police-tamilnadu/amp/ (Google Organic Search for Mobile browsers)

**Changes:** Recently I have moved from Siteground to VPS. Settings were optimised. One thing I'm missing is Siteground's Cache. Now I'm using W3 Total Cache Plugin.

**Revenue:** I have lost nearly 60% of revenue in this last 30 days. I'm trying different settings but yet google cache doesn't show my ads.
Note: My Website does not contain any pirated materials or unpopular niche. Even if Google thinks in that way then ads should not be displayed on my domain too. So the issue is only with Google amp cache viewer.

**Expectations:** 
1) Need to show ads even when viewing through google AMP cache viewer.
2) Do not need to use google AMP cache and so to show AMP pages directly from my domain.

Comment: I see the advertisements working in both links.

Comment: Thank you, James, for trying. Wordpress Plugin Support helped me to resolve this issue. 
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/adsense-ads-not-working-in-google-amp-cache/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the AMP plugin settings. Just to turn off viewability option in ads. I have also attached the url which helped to resolve the issue.
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/adsense-ads-not-working-in-google-amp-cache/